# Android database trouble

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have couple questions regarding the use of SQLite for my Android App. I think my issues are pretty basic but I just can't seem to figure out the database aspect of the app.

1. I want the user to enter some data in, lets say Activity A. So the data is now stored in a database. I then want Activity B to retrieve the Activity A data from the database and use it for certain calculations in Activity B.
2. The data that the user enters, I want it to stay on the screen once the user enters it, closes the app, and then reopens the app. I assume this has also to do with the database. Right now, once I enter in the data in Activity A, then navigate to Activity B, and then come back to Activity A and the data is gone.

I am not looking for the exact code to make this work. I am looking for mostly how the database works and if I can even do the 2 things that I mentioned above. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain this to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the user to enter some data in, lets say Activity A. So the data is now stored in a database. I then want Activity B to retrieve the Activity A data from the database and use it for certain calculations in Activity B.

This problem can be solved easily with the help of a single [SharedPrefrence](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). SQLite Databases should be used when you want to stored structured data within the app not for storing just a simple name-value pair. In case you need any SQLite tutorials for android:

[Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

[Android SQLite database and content provider - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

and the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now how would i go about the issue 2.?